# How to delete Bugzilla saved-searches as administrator?

Tags: bugzilla, cleanup

Users can create and save searches in
`Preferences // Bugzilla – Saved Searches`

Here they can publish them to a group `Share With a Group` and they will be listed for all users. Over the years the list is filled with useless `Saved Searches` by inactive users.

How can I delete Bugzilla saved-searches as administrator?[image: Screenshot of obsolete entry in Preferences // Bugzilla – Saved Searches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugzilla has a "sudo" feature where an administrator can log in as a specific user for troubleshooting.  It's disabled by default because it's easy to abuse.  If you go in the params and turn that on, you can use it to log in as that user and unshare their queries.

Documentation for this feature is [here](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/administering/users.html#impersonating-users).

Comment: With your hint I found https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/useradmin.html you could use this and screenshots to enrich your answer for the readers. The readers will thank you with up votes.